# Can't install Catalyst 12.8

Tags: ati, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

I can not install fglrx ATI drivers/Catalyst 12.8. I have tried installing AMA Catalyst 12.8 using this guide: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-amd-catalyst-128-on-ubuntu.html

When I reach the part of installing with sudo sh amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
, I get the following error:

[image]

When I run it using the --force option, I get this message: [image]

How can I fix these errors and install Catalyst 12.8?

Comment: Well... did you run the installer before this?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I know how to install ATI Catalyst video drivers, I am not asking for guidance on the correct way. I am looking for a solution to the errors I am facing.

Comment: I have run the installer before, but before this attempt I tried removin any previous fglrx drivers, but running sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem. Catalyst 12.8 dosent support Ubuntu 12.10. You have to download and install Beta Version Catalyst.

Answer (score 1):

Resolve the problem and correctly instalation Catalyst. It is a Bug.

First if you have instaled drivers pls unistal them. After this enter comand.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
```

After this install driver from System settings/software resources/additional drivers and select AMD graphicks accelerator

Answer (score 0):

As mention on the page open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and;

Uninstall first the old driver with the following commands:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Install base on [this page](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/08/install-amd-catalyst-128-on-ubuntu.html):

```
cd /tmp

chmod +x amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run

sudo sh amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
```

Comment: dominic@dominic-Gateway:~$ chmod +x amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
chmod: cannot access `amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run': No such file or directory

Comment: dominic@dominic-Gateway:~$ sudo sh amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run
sh: 0: Can't open amd-driver-installer-8.982-x86.x86_64.run

Comment: Where's you file located? home or downloads? If on downloads, make sure to : `cd Downloads` then run back above command.

Comment: "One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing fglrx driver. Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without tools. Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended. See /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more info." What tools am I missing?

Comment: Check [AMD Mainpage](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English). My advice to see this first. [Link 1](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?72937-12-8-up-on-site-but-broken-link&p=281473#post281473) | [Link 2](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2MTY)